# How can I slide my div on hover without it sliding over the padding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover, slide

I've been searching for hours already on how to slide down a certain div but it doesn't seem to be working out. What I'm trying to do here is slide down the `.permalink` when you hover the `#entry` and the `#entry` under it slides down with it. The script worked before but what it does is just slide down over the padding and the `#entry` under it doesn't.

Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#entry").mouseover(function () {
    $(".permalink").stop().slideDown("slow");
});
$("#entry").mouseout(function () {
    $(".permalink").slideUp("slow");
});});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/umws6nrk/3/)

It'd be awesome if you guys could help me out with this. Thank you! x

EDIT:
Here's a link to my [blog](http://asphyxiated.tk/tagged/photoset). I tagged some photosets in there so you'll know what I'm trying to work on. I am using the code that @Csdtesting posted. It worked on the fiddle but not on my blog.

Comment: Off topic: You have multiple elements with the same ID. This is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave`instead!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".photo").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find('.permalink').stop().slideDown("slow");
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(".permalink").slideUp("slow");
    });
});
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/umws6nrk/9//](http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/umws6nrk/9/)

Comment: See the fiddle plz .The old implementation just didn't work.My version works...! @Ely help me!

Comment: They both work in the same manner in Chrome. Re-read the question more carefully. Your demo pushes the second row down, which is the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61854/discussion-between-csdtesting-and-isherwood).

Comment: @Csdtesting @isherwood When I looked at the fiddle, it looked like it was the closest to what I wanted since it pushes down the `#entry` below it to make room for the `.permalink` but when I tried it on my blog, it doesn't push it and still goes over the padding so when you hover, there's no more padding between them. Here's my blog http://asphyxiated.tk I'm trying to do it on the photosets when you hover at it. I am also using masonry. I tried to use it on my original fiddle but I don't know how to edit the code to make it work there.

Comment: Yes for that reason i created that fiddle .It is more logical.So at your blog maybe there is some CSS that breaks this implementation.

Comment: I think it's the masonry that breaks it, because when I removed it, the code started working (I also didn't have to use jQuery for it to slide down, just CSS), then when I put it back, it's gone again. I've been searching for hours on how to make it work with masonry just like this: [link](http://elphinstonebasic.tumblr.com/) - hover on the quote post. I also used `column-count` and `column-gap` instead of masonry. It worked fine at the first column, but the second column removed the animations. Example: [link](http://codepen.io/am_mutable/full/KrJcL)

Answer (score 0):

You can animate padding or margin to match the height of your permalink element:

```
.entry {
    ...
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}

$(".entry").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find(".permalink").stop().slideDown("slow");
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'margin-bottom': '0'
    }, 'slow');
});
$(".entry").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).find(".permalink").stop().slideUp("slow");
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'margin-bottom': '18'
    }, 'slow');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/umws6nrk/7)

There's a 1-pixel twitch in my demo, possibly due to a height rounding peculiarity. I'm out of time for now, though.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering! The code doesn't work for me though, I don't know why. I tried it on my blog but it doesn't work on it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong with your code...  The answer to your main question, if I understand it correctly, is that the permalink is inside the div element for .photo.  Therefore, when the permalink slides down, its container (.photo), must also expand to make room for it.  Move the permalink outside the .photo div.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/umws6nrk/3/)

```
<div id="entry">
        <div class="photo">
            <img src="https://38.media.tumblr.com/358b80be4c70049645ce41fdc3a664bf/tumblr_mz4c7ymrJJ1rb40pco1_500.gif">

        </div>
            <div class="permalink"><a class="link" href="">PERMALINK</a>

            </div>
    </div>
```

Also, you should use mouseenter and mouseleave as it was said above to alleviate the "jumpiness" of the mouse hover.  Look them up on jQuery.com to see what the differences are.

Lastly, you should only have one unique ID per page. Having all four photos with elements of ID = #entry is why when you rollo over the first one all four permalinks slide down, and the function doesn't work on the remaining three.

EDIT:

OK I think I understand the question now.  isherwood has the right idea. Though you do not need any additional animation. Its pushing the second row down because there is no room for the permalink, so of course it needs to push it.  All you need to do is add some space for the permalink to inhabit from the beginning.  The easiest way would be to just assign a height to the #entry elements.

[new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umws6nrk/10/)

Comment: Then I do not understand your question, please clarify